# duplicated exception on python

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, exception

Don't try to find some logical explanation for the below code. It's just to simply reproduce the case.
The issue is that I got an Exception wrapped in another Exception while I'm expecting only one of those.
Python code is following:

```
class TEST(object):
    def __init__(self, param, content=[]):
        self.param = param
        self.content = content

    def test_rec(self):
        try:
            collection = ''.join([c.test_rec() for c in self.content])
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception('Exception [%s] in %s' % (e, self.__class__))
        return collection+self.param

class TEST2(TEST):
    pass

a = TEST('1')
b = TEST2('2')
c = TEST2('3')
a.content = [b, c]
b.content = 1

print a.test_rec()
```

Current Exception is:

```
Exception: Exception [Exception ['int' object is not iterable] in <class '__main__.TEST2'>] in <class '__main__.TEST'>
```

Expected is:

```
Exception: Exception ['int' object is not iterable] in <class '__main__.TEST2'>
```

Comment: Makes sense to me that you have an exception inside an exception. `a.test_rec()` calls `b.test_rec()`. b.test_rec crashes, catches the error, and raises another one. a.test_rec catches that error and raises another one. You have two exceptions, hence "Exception [ Exception".

Answer (score 0):

when you add an additional print statement you see what happens:

```
def test_rec(self):
    try:
        collection = ''.join([c.test_rec() for c in self.content])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception('<%s> in %s' % (e, self.__class__))
    return collection+self.param
```

the print statement gives:

```
'int' object is not iterable
<'int' object is not iterable> in <class '__main__.TEST2'>
```

the final exception is then

```
Exception: <<'int' object is not iterable> in <class '__main__.TEST2'>> in <class '__main__.TEST'>
```

`a.test_rec()` -> `b.test_rec()`; this raises the Exception, catches it and reraises it. this in turn gets caught by and reraised by `a.test_rec()`.

Comment: yup. i understand that. i just don't get how to avoid such chain. finally i do want to see the main exception, and i do expect program exit on that exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. A bit ugly but it works:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

class TEST(object):
    def __init__(self, param, content=[]):
        self.param = param
        self.content = content

    def test_rec(self):
        try:
            collection = ''.join([c.test_rec() for c in self.content])
        except MyException:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            raise MyException('Exception [%s] in %s' % (e, self.__class__))
        return collection+self.param

class TEST2(TEST):
    pass

a = TEST('1')
b = TEST2('2')
c = TEST2('3')
a.content = [b, c]
b.content = 1

print a.test_rec()
```